# Powershell -not and -like filtering into files

Tags: powershell

I've written a script that reads File 1: (List of Game Titles) and compares it to a list of (Phrases) in File 2: If any part of the string from the records from File 1 contain any of the phrases from File 2, then it's a match, otherwise all others will be written to an exception file. The script will however automatically exclude records that contain "Pickels" by default.

```
Examples

The Pickels Game -> "Pickels" is auto excluded -> Append record to bad_out
The Moon Game -> "Moon" is a listed phrases -> Append record to good_out
The Red Unicorn Ultra Game -> "Red Unicorn" is a listed phrase -> Append record to good_out
The Red Unicorn Pickles Game -> "Pickels" is auto excluded -> Append record to bad_out
```

The challenge is that script appears to be filter out Pickles but I'm not sure if it's actually filtering out the list in File 1 against the list of phrases from File 2. It has written all qualifying records in the "bad_out" file, while the "good_out" file is empty. It suppose to write all qualifying records from File 1 into good_out, and all mismatches or containing the word "Pickels" to the bad_out file.

```
# read the import import sheet
$spreadTagList = Import-Csv "game_tiles.csv"
$iniData = Import-Csv "negative_phrases.csv"

# initialize the output arrays
$matchingRecords =@()
$nonMatchingRecords = @()

#loop through each record
foreach ($tagRecord in $spreadTagList) {
    if ($tagRecord -notlike "*Pickles*") {
        $matched = $false
foreach ($iniRecord in $iniData) {
    if ($tagRecord -like $iniRecord) {
        $matchingRecords += $tagRecord
           $matched = $true
           break

            }
        }

if (-not $matched) {
    $nonMatchingRecords += $tagRecord
        }
    }

}

# write matched records to out.xls file
$matchingRecords | Export-Csv "test_good.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# write unmatched records to exceptions.xls file
$nonMatchingRecords | Export-Csv "test_bad.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What are the Column Names in your Csvs? if they dont have a Column then you should probably be using `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv`. Perhaps add a few example lines of both files to your question

Comment: Neiter CSV have columns per say. Maybe that's the challenge? Both the source List file, and the comparison list files just have a column of strings

Comment: well yeah, then there is no reason to use `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv`. Should be using `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`. Neither you should be using the `.csv` extension as that would be misleading. `.txt` would be more appropriate don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all based on comments, it's clear that `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` are not the right cmdlets to use in this case as what you have right now are just plain *unstructured* text files, so you should use `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` instead.

As for how to approach the logic of your code, an easy way to do it is to create a regex pattern with all the "good" words and then use a condition that if the line matches `Pickles` or **does not match** the regex pattern, then it goes to the `test_bad` file, else, it goes to `test_good`.

Using the info we have in your question as an example, the regex pattern we could use is `\b(?:Moon|Red Unicorn)\b`, but later on in the actual code, the pattern is auto-generated based on the contents of `negative_phrases.csv`.

```bash
$test = @(
    'The Pickels Game'
    'The Moon Game'
    'The Red Unicorn Ultra Game'
    'The Red Unicorn Pickles Game'
)

$test | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match 'Pickles' -or $_ -notmatch '\b(?:Moon|Red Unicorn)\b') {
        return "Bad Output: [$_]"
    }

    "Good Output: [$_]"
}

# Bad Output: [The Pickels Game]
# Good Output: [The Moon Game]
# Good Output: [The Red Unicorn Ultra Game]
# Bad Output: [The Red Unicorn Pickles Game]
```

So based on this logic, we can do the following:

```bash
$iniData = Get-Content 'negative_phrases.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }

$pattern = "\b(?:$($iniData -join '|'))\b"

$badOutput = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
Get-Content 'game_tiles.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # if this line matches `Pickles` or does not match the regex OR pattern
    if ($_ -match 'Pickles' -or $_ -notmatch $pattern) {
        # add it to the list
        $badOutput.Add($_)
        # and go to next line
        return
    }

    # else, output this line to `test_good` file
    $_
} | Set-Content test_good.txt

# if there were lines not matching the pattern or matching `Pickles`
if ($badOutput.Count -gt 0) {
    # output them to the `test_bad` file
    $badOutput | Set-Content test_bad.txt
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant. This worked out beautifully. I created a rules_ file that contains all the good vs bad rules to consider and it integrated nicely into this patterned approach. Thanks!

Comment: great to hear @NanoNet ! happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, if I may:

```
# Load file contents
$TitleList = Get-Content -Path .\nome_4.ext  #  'game_tiles.csv'
$NegativeList = Get-Content -Path .\nome_5.ext # 'negative_phrases.csv'

# set Bad Word
$NegativeWord = 'Pickles'

# prepare temporary lists
$GoodTitles = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$BadTitles = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()


# Loop Time!
Foreach ($Title in $TitleList) {
    if (
        $Title -in $NegativeList -or
        $Title -match $NegativeWord
    ) {
        $BadTitles.Add($Title)
    }
    else {
        $GoodTitles.Add($Title)
    }
}

# also in One-Line form
# $TitleList.foreach({ ($_ -in $NegativeList -or $_ -match $NegativeWord) ? $BadTitles.Add($_) : $GoodTitles.Add($_) })
# BONUS: pipeline version.
# $TitleList | ForEach-Object -Process { ($_ -in $NegativeList -or $_ -match $NegativeWord) ? $BadTitles.Add($_) : $GoodTitles.Add($_) }


# One could actually append the contents live in the foreach loop, thus avoiding the need of saving the results in List
# But unless there is some real NEED for real-time writing, waiting for the logic to end and then write the file at once is MUCH more efficient
# Plus gives the chance to modify or recycle the results before writing them in the future should it ever become necessary
$GoodTitles | Out-File -FilePath '.\test_good.txt' 
$BadTitles | Out-File -FilePath '.\test_bad.txt'
```

Comment: This is also a very great and clean solution. Only caveat (and I found out recently) is that I have a long list of both good (allowances) and bad phrases (exceptions) to consider. So I ended up leveraging the prior solution but retro-fitting it with a means to read the two lists and filter away. Thanks however for the contribution - this is helpful